# validation php not working?

Tags: php, validation, email

The following is the  email verification code for my site.

The verification url sent to the user's email is as follows:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/valid.php?confr=2774405&userid=2`

**Extra notes** :

1) `key` is a column in my database which gets a random value on registration.

2) if `$verify == 1` and `password_in_db=== user_entered_password`, then login takes place in the login page.

```
<?php

    include 'connect.php';

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT verify,key FROM users WHERE id = '$_GET['userid']'");
    $details = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $verify = $details['verify'];
    $confirm2 = $details['key'];

    if($verify == "1") {
        echo "Link Expired . Go to our login page :";
    } else {
        if (isset($_GET["confr"]) && isset($_GET["userid"])) {
            $confirm1 =$_GET["confr"];

            if($confirm1 == $confirm2) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`verify`) VALUES ('1') WHERE id = '$_GET["userid"]' ;");
                echo "Thank You For Registering with us . Go to your LOGIN PAGE Here ";
            } else {
                echo "Invalid link ";
                echo "Go to your LOGIN PAGE Here ";
            }
        } //  of if isset
    } // of  else part
?>
```

Code for connect.php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("host", "username", "pass");  //connects to the server
    mysql_select_db("database_name");  //selects the database
?>
```

The problem is that it is giving me  a blank screen .

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (\`verify\`) VALUES ('1') WHERE id = '$_GET["userid"]' ;");` pretty sure you can't do that

Comment: It should be `mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (\`verify\`) VALUES ('1') WHERE id = '".$_GET["userid"]."' ;");`.

Comment: your code is perfectly helpful for hacker(bad guy) because you are not escaping the request ($_GET) and this means that its vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Actually this is giving me a blank screen . and not even an error

Comment: Check your error logs at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Sorry, i think that is not possible since this page is uploaded to a free hosting site.

Comment: try echoing something outside the if statements see if the page is loading put one below the include

Answer (score 0):

i believe the error lies in the sql

when ever i use a "WHERE" statement i always define as a variable, try this

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$user_id = $_GET["userid"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT verify,key FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
$details = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$verify = $details['verify'];
$confirm2 = $details['key'];
if($verify == "1"){
echo "Link Expired . Go to our login page :";
}
else{
if (isset($_GET["confr"]) && isset($_GET["userid"]))
{
$confirm1 =$_GET["confr"];
if($confirm1 == $confirm2){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`verify`) VALUES ('1') WHERE id = '$user_id'");

echo "Thank You For Registering with us . Go to your LOGIN PAGE Here ";
}
else {
echo "Invalid link ";
echo "Go to your LOGIN PAGE Here ";
}
} //  of if isset
} // of  else part

?>
```

also, you have a semi colon in the insert sql

Comment: Now $confirm2 = $details['key']; is not giving any output

Comment: You are missing the "while" loop, while ther is data to collect, it will keep going, without the "while" it gets just the 1 result

$query = mysql_query("SELECT verify,key FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
while ($details = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$verify = $details['verify'];
$confirm2 = $details['key'];
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$user_id = $_GET["userid"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT verify,key FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'"); 
   while ($details = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
      $verify = $details['verify']; 
      $confirm2 = $details['key']; 
    }
if($verify == "1"){
    echo "Link Expired . Go to our login page :";
}
 else{
   if (isset($_GET["confr"]) && isset($_GET["userid"]))
 {
   $confirm1 =$_GET["confr"];
   if($confirm1 == $confirm2){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`verify`) VALUES ('1') WHERE id = '$user_id'");

echo "Thank You For Registering with us . Go to your LOGIN PAGE Here ";
}
else {
echo "Invalid link ";
echo "Go to your LOGIN PAGE Here ";
    }
  } //  of if isset
} // of  else part

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: insert statement has no where - as long as you dont use "insert into select..."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert.html

Comment: Now the code started working, but the mysql_query ie 

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (verify) VALUES ('1') WHERE id = '$userid';"); 

is not working . Can you give me a suggestion

Comment: As said above insert has no where, so it must be `insert into users (verify) values ('1')`. But i think you dont want to insert a row, but update it: `update users set verify = '1' where id = ".$userid .";"`